# Node proxy origin rewrite while matching routes

Tags: node.js, proxy, http-proxy

I would like to set up a reverse proxy for certain development purposes. I have two services up and running already on these locations:

- `http:localhost:9000/application/rest` (restful api)
- `http:localhost:4000/application` (serving my react app)

I would like to set up a proxy which will route:

- `http:localhost/application/rest/*` => `http:localhost:9000/application/rest/*`
- `http:localhost/application/*` => `http:localhost:4000/application/*`

In other words I would like to rewrite origin while matching routes. I was looking at the https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy, but I didn't find this option. What are other options?

Comment: And whats the problem ?

Comment: I've tried all sorts of solutions with `node-http-proxy` which I found and non of them worked. Take a look down below. I finally found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using `express` and `http-proxy-middleware`:

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();
app.use('/application/rest', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:9000', changeOrigin: true }));
app.use('/application', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:4000', changeOrigin: true }));
app.listen(80);
```

Maybe it will help someone.